# Find an Inverse for the Exponential Integral function

Tags: python, function, exponential

I have a program where I have to find x.
But I have to use the special function Ei - the exponential integral, and x is inside the argument of Ei. 
So Python isn't recognizing it.

> ei(m*x) = t*e^r + ei(c)

Here the RHS is a constant alongwith m.
I want to find the value of x, and then append it to a list. But Python isn't able to do this.

```
from scipy import special
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Y = []
X = np.arange(0,10,.1)
for i in X:
    y = scipy.special.expi(i)
    Y.append(y)

N_0 = 2
t_f = 100
r = 2
K = 100
N_t = [N_0,]
t = np.arange(0,100,1)
for i in t:
    l = i*e**r + scipy.special.expi(r*N_t[i]/K)
    N_t.append(l)
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.plot(t,N_t)
plt.show
```

Comment: So what does your actual code look like?

Comment: Are you even using Scipy? [expi](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expi.html#scipy.special.expi) sounds exactly like what you are looking for

Comment: I am. But scipy function ei is not able to calculate a variable inside the argument of the function. It can easily calculate ei for constant values, but not find e(x) = C.

Comment: You can't do `e(x) = C` on paper either - you need to solve this equation for `x` first (or use some specialized software/library for solving equations)

Comment: @UnholySheep Scipy has a collection of root finding functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected some mistakes in your code to give the following. You should compare this with your code line by line.

```
from scipy.special import expi
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Y = []
X = np.arange(0,10,.1)
for i in X:
    y = expi(i)
    Y.append(y)

N_0 = 2
t_f = 100
r = 2
K = 100
N_t = [N_0,]
t = np.arange(0,100,1)
for i in t:
    l = i*np.exp(r) + expi(r*N_t[i]/K)
    N_t.append(l)
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.plot(t,N_t)
plt.show()
```

However, there is still one possible flaw that I notice and can't resolve. You plot X and t together in the same graph at the end yet X ranges over 0 to 10 and t ranges over 0 to 100. Is this what you intended?

Also matplotlib complains that the lengths of the vectors supplied to it in the second call to plot are not the same.